# Justificar conteúdo de uma variável

Tags: php, html

Estou trabalhando com textos, lendo o que foi digitado pelo usuário e guardando na variável *assunto*. Gostaria que, quando a variável fosse chamada, seu conteúdo fosse mostrado na tela com o alinhamento justificado. Porém já tentei de algumas formas como:

```
echo "<div style='text-align: justify;'>".$assunto."</div>";

echo "<p align='justify'>".$assunto."</p>";
```

E não tive resultado. Como posso fazer para mostrar o conteúdo de uma variável com alinhamento justificado?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

É pelo CSS, assim como você tentou fazer no primeiro exemplo, mas é apenas `justify`, não `justifictify`. Veja um exemplo:

```css
p {
  text-align: justify;
}
```

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam non gravida nisi. Fusce in nisi ut lorem aliquam tempus. Mauris aliquet maximus nulla a luctus. Etiam finibus nisl quis dignissim lacinia. Praesent arcu nunc, tristique quis dui eu, finibus ultrices lorem. Proin eget leo ultricies, scelerisque nulla et, blandit metus. Aliquam tincidunt lorem neque, sit amet maximus nulla cursus in. Nullam vel odio rhoncus, accumsan elit et, aliquam diam. Duis et leo vel metus iaculis tincidunt non a lacus. Nulla a feugiat augue, ut tincidunt erat. Maecenas nec interdum odio, eu luctus risus. Suspendisse sed erat lectus. Proin fermentum consequat justo sit amet imperdiet. Vestibulum tellus eros, facilisis nec imperdiet non, consectetur id turpis. Sed tempus congue mauris nec sagittis. Suspendisse at ante sit amet metus consectetur accumsan.</p>
<p>Ut aliquet tincidunt odio, nec sodales est. Cras faucibus vestibulum urna, nec tincidunt nisi iaculis et. Ut condimentum nunc eu sapien pharetra, vel pretium risus interdum. Suspendisse gravida leo at tellus gravida, sit amet rhoncus eros sagittis. Sed tristique ante lectus. Phasellus a malesuada lacus. Sed nec eros eu nibh scelerisque laoreet. Mauris non lacus vel ex maximus varius at auctor mi. Morbi nunc augue, iaculis eget libero id, efficitur dapibus sem. Integer viverra, neque quis egestas consectetur, massa elit sollicitudin orci, vel dapibus diam nibh ac arcu. Nulla tristique quis mi in facilisis. Nulla arcu ipsum, ullamcorper vel dictum ac, pharetra et ligula. Nullam congue vestibulum bibendum. Suspendisse aliquet porta mauris nec mattis. Morbi tempus eros sed dolor molestie convallis ac sit amet enim.</p>
```